# Python regex error: "cannot refer to an open group"

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am creating rules for a reddit automoderator. It gets its rules from a YAML config file and the regexes are interpreted as Python regex.

I am trying to make the following regular expression work:

```
(https?://[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?+-=\\.&]+\\.\\w{2,6})([\\S\\s]*\\1)
```

When I test it on https://pythex.org/ it works perfectly to achieve what I want.

Unfortunately my group reference at the end of the expression is causing an error when I copy the same regex into the config file:

> Generated an invalid regex for `body (regex)`: cannot refer to an open
>   group

I have also tried this version with everything escaped just to make sure that the characters weren't interfering in any way:

```
(https?://[\\w\\d\\:\\#\\@\\%\\/\\;\\$\\(\\)\\~\\_\\?\\+\\-\\=\\.&]+\\.\\w{2,6})([\\S\\s]*\\1)
```

But I still get the same error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try to print the regex? Also, try it without the `( [\S\s]* \1 )` and see if it errors.

Comment: I cannot print the regex, as I am just setting rules in YAML and they are being interpreted by someone else's python code. It does not have errors without the end group.

Comment: That error is thrown if you reference a group inside the group like [this](https://pythex.org/?regex=(https%3F%3A%2F%2F%5B%5Cw%5Cd%3A%23%40%25%2F%3B%24()~_%3F%2B-%3D%5C.%26%5D%2B%5C.%5Cw%7B2%2C6%7D%5C1)(%5B%5CS%5Cs%5D*)&test_string=http%3A%2F%2Fhel.o.com%2F%20%20http%3A%2F%2Fhel.o.com%2F&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) so it could be the closing `)` is not being seen.

Comment: Then, remove the end group and just put `\1` at the end, as a test.

Comment: And, it wouldn't hurt to escape the forward slashes for a test `((https?:\/\/[\w\d:#@%\/;$()~_?+\-=\.&]+\.\w{2,6})([\S\s]*\1)` Note that you have to escape the dash in the class if you want it to be literal `\-`

Comment: I have now tried this: `(https?:\\/\\/[\\w\\d\\:\\#\\@\\%\\/\\;\\$\\(\\)\\~\\_\\?\\+\\-\\=\\.\\&]+\\.\\w{2,6})\\1` . Forward slashes are escaped and I have removed the last group and just put `\1`. I still get the same error.

Comment: So you've escaped everything in the class and removed the trailing group and just put the backreference `\1` there. Does it still throw an error ?

Comment: Yes, it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by changing the group selection to `\2` instead of `\1`.

It turned out that YAML or AutoModerator were automatically putting parentheses around the whole expression, so any group references within must be 1 more than you would initially expect.

I had thought that this was the problem at the start, and tried the fix explained above, however due to a separate issue with the AutoModerator code, the fix had not appeared to have worked. All resolved now though; thanks for your patience and help.